# Discord Python Reaction Role

Tags: python, discord

I want that my bot add the role "User" to a user who react with a heart. But it doesn't work.
My code:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.emoji == "❤️":
        user = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="User")
        await user.add_roles(user)
```

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are there any error codes? What is your traceback?

Comment: Thank you. My Bot don't add the role and there's absolutely no error or something. I tryed many other variants. Nothing won't work

Comment: Do you have Intents enabled?

Comment: Did you verify that the code is executed at all?

Comment: @Dominik I had an older discordpy version and intents was not enabled. I fixed that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a different event here called `on_raw_reaction_add`. You can find the documentation for it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add).

With that new event you would have to rewrite your code a bit and add/remove some things.

***Your new code:***

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix", intents=intents) #Import Intents

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id) # Get guild
    member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # Get the member out of the guild
    # The channel ID should be an integer:
    if payload.channel_id == 812510632360149066: # Only channel where it will work
        if str(payload.emoji) == "❌": # Your emoji
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, id=YourRoleID) # Role ID
        else:
            role = get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)
        if role is not None: # If role exists
            await payload.member.add_roles(role)
            print(f"Added {role}")
```

***What did we do?***

- Use `payload`
- Used the role ID instead of the name so you can always change that
- Limited the reaction to one channel, in all the others it will not work
- Turned the emoji into a `str`

*Make sure to turn your Intents in the [DDPortal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) on and import them!*

Comment: It worked. Thank you! I have one question. What exactly do payload and for what I need the member variable? Its unused

Comment: I added `member` as you need it for `on_raw_reaction_remove`, can be removed from `on_raw_reaction_add` though. You can have a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) for your payload question.