# Discord py - Gives a role when the user adds a reaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, roles

I want to create a **ChangeLog** room where updates are displayed. The **on_message** part works without problem.
[Screen of the message displayed in the salon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW2eW.png)

And the **on_raw_reaction_add** part does not work. There are no errors in the console. The user would normally have an additional role **(ChangeLog)** when clicking on the bell emoji.
[Screen Role name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXfmh.png)

My code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if (message.channel.id == 846081235465797662):
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        else:
            await message.delete()
            channel = bot.get_channel(846081235465797662)
            
            desc = await message.channel.send(
                f"**⚙️ CHANGELOG DU {ddmmYY} - <@&851702594837413929>**\n\n" + 
                message.content)
            await desc.add_reaction('')


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    canal = payload.channel_id
    message = payload.message_id

    role = discord.utils.get(bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).roles,
           name="ChangeLog")
    membre = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_member(payload.user_id)


    if canal == 846861087600148540 and emoji == "":
        await membre.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Do you have reaction intents enabled? As the [API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) sais: `This requires Intents.reactions to be enabled.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Python Reaction Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847364/discord-python-reaction-role)

Answer (score 0):

incorrect code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

    emoji = payload.emoji.name

    ...

    if canal == 846861087600148540 and emoji == "":
        await membre.add_roles(role)
```

`payload.emoji.name == ""`?
correct code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    emoji = payload.emoji.__str__()
    ...
```

try it